# Download large data in background android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android development.I have assign a task which i don't know how to starts so wanted help.
The task is that i will be needing to download a large amount of data from server and store it in my local database and all this things should be done in background.There are few scenarios which i will need to consider.
1)While downloading the data and if in between the internet connections goes the whole downloading process should not start from beginning ,it should start from the point where the internet connection goes off.So how will i achieve all this??
Any help will be most appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: kindly have look at the            http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html  and  https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html  Get an idea of what your task is about then proceed

Comment: Good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Sir can you tell  what to do if the internet connection goes in between while i have downloaded half of the data